# Refresh image - observable Angular

Tags: angular, firebase, onchange, angularfire

I use angular 6, firebase and angularfire.

I display my image like that :

```
import { AngularFireStorage } from 'angularfire2/storage';

  @Component({
  selector: 'app-geo',
  templateUrl: '  <img mat-card-image [src]="profileUrl | async" >

})
export class GeoComponent {


profileUrl: Observable<string | null>;

constructor( private storage: AngularFireStorage) 
  { 
  const ref = this.storage.ref('live/live.jpg');
  this.profileUrl = ref.getDownloadURL();        }
```

But my image changes every 30 second but not in my app. I must reload my page to see changement.

Is it normal ?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're saying that the file uploaded into storage (*at location `this.storage.ref('live/live.jpg');` in storage*) changes every 30 seconds - as in, someone else is re-uploading a different image overtop the existing file every 30 seconds? And you want that reflected on the end-user's screen? Yes - the fact that you have to reload the page to see the new image is completely normal and expected.

There's no implementation for subscribing to a file like you've described, not in Firebase anyways. If it's possible for you to accomplish what you need via [image carousels](https://www.google.com/search?q=image+carousels), simply downloading all the images you want in one go and then cycling through them, that would definitely be easier for you to accomplish.

If you really need **real-time** photo changes you will have to use Firebase's real-time database or Firestore, and subscribe to a set of data - that set of data being the URLs for recently uploaded images. As part of the upload process (*or as an automatically triggered cloud function*) the finalized URL would be added to the queue/list of URLs. You could then use a package like AngularFire2 to help you subscribe to that queue/list of URLs.

Comment: okay. thank you very much for the explanation. I was looking to get my url download firebase from python (script that takes the photos and sends to firebase) but without success ...